# Minhook crashes when the function returns

Tags: c++, dll, hook, reverse-engineering

I'm having some issues with Minhook. When the modified function returns a value, application getting crashed. And I don't quite understand what the problem is.

As I understand it, the hooked function must return the original function with parameters, these parameters can be changed in the hook function.
This is the function I want to hook, taken from decompiler. I did not copied the function code because you would most likely be tired of scrolling through the page:

```
__int64 __fastcall SendPacket(int eNetMessageType, _QWORD *a2, __int64 _ENetPeer);
```

This is the original function that I have already moved to my code:

```
void(__thiscall* SendPacket)(int, long double*, __int64);
```

And this is the modified (hooked) function:

```
void __fastcall SendPacketLog(int eNetMessageType, long double* a2, __int64 _ENetPeer) {
std::cout << "[SendPacketLog]\nType: " << eNetMessageType << "\nUnknown: " << a2 << "\nENetPeer: " << _ENetPeer << "\n\n";

return SendPacket(eNetMessageType, a2, _ENetPeer);
}
```

The modified function should simply log the parameters of the function and then return the original function in the end. I manage to get the log, which is what the modified function should do, but immediately after that the game crashes.

In general, I can guess about the incorrect transfer of variables from the disassembler (From C and assembly to C ++, but at first glance everything is correct).
I attached a debugger to the process and when I crashed I got an error: "access violation while executing at address"
I also tried to return the value 0. Someone suggested this to me, but it did not help, it just saved from crashes, but broke the application.

Comment: The original function has return type `__int64`, so why do you return `void`?

Comment: @ssbssa , actually, I originally used __int64, but after desperate attempts, I googled the size in bytes of __int64 and found out that void has the same size. Changing this to __int64 unfortunately didn't change anything.

Comment: `void` had no size, maybe you mean `void *` (if it's a 64bit application).

Comment: @ssbssa , Generally I meant `void`. I didn't knew that `void` has no size. Also i've just tried `void *` and unfortunately it didn't help.